# I need to figure out how to bind my enum in my class library to the radio buttons in my application

Tags: vb.net, enums, radio-button, class-library

I can not figure out how to bind my Enum in my class library to my radio buttons to display that one of them is checked and pulls up an answer from the enum
the names of my radio button are radCopper, radNickel, radGold, radSilver, radPalladium, radPlatinum, and radZinc.
This is the Enum I need to use in my class library

```
Namespace CoinCollection
`Public Class Coin
Public Enum Metal
            Gold
            Silver
            Platinum
            Copper
            Zinc
            Nickel
            Palladium
        End Enum`
This is the button I need to display the radio button checked when clicked

Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
Dim Met = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Coinn.Metal))
        If radCopper.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show("Copper")
        End If
```

This button also binds the other Enum in my class library to my drop down list which is currently working

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        Dim Curr = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Coinn.Currency))
        MessageBox.Show(cboCurrency.SelectedItem, GetType(Coinn.Currency).Name)
```

Comment: That is not data binding in any meaningful sense of the term, so that rather obscures more what you are trying to do.  In the `btnInsert` event are trying to figure out which radio is selected?  Why not use a CBO like for currency?  A MessageBox isnt great use of the result so what is really supposed to happen with it?  Stored to a var?

Comment: It is suppose to alert the user of the currency and metal they picked from the radio boxes and combo box using the enums when the button is clicked

Comment: @vgingin you could look here to start with https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-bind-enum-to-f5f38059/sourcecode?fileId=84377&pathId=1375465726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no binding to `RadioButtons`. You just need to use some code to get the appropriate value. You might do so by index after the fact, e.g.

```
Dim radioButtons = {radGold, radSilver, ...}
Dim checkedIndex = Array.IndexOf(radioButtons, radioButtons.Single(Function(rb) rb.Checked))
Dim metalValue = DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Metal)), Metal())(checkedIndex)
```

Alternatively, you might use the `Tag` properties of the controls before the fact, e.g.

```
Dim radioButtons = {radGold, radSilver, ...}
Dim metalValues = DirectCast([Enum].GetValues(GetType(Metal)), Metal())

For i = 0 To radioButtons.GetUpperBound(0)
    radioButtons(i).Tag = metalValues(i)
Next
```

You can then get the appropriate value from the checked `RadioButton` after the fact, e.g.

```
Dim metalValue = DirectCast(radioButtons.Single(Function(rb) rb.Checked).Tag, Metal)
```

Comment: Note that I have addressed some issue in the syntax of the code.